# Run a few seconds of simulation just after loading a scene

Tags: unity, simulations, savegame, timestep

I'm looking for a way to execute 3 to 15 seconds of simulation once a scene is loaded.

The problem is: some objects can be left suspended in motion while the player exits the scene. their state is saved. And the player can come back later to see the simulation resume. I have solved this type of problems in the past by running the physics engine in parallel for multiple scenes, but I could not find a way to do this in Unity.

I understand [Time.timeScale](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) could be used here, but how should I proceed to hide/not display the scene while the simulation runs or run all the time ticks in one pass before display?

Comment: I think the Time.timeScale (and Time.fixedDeltaTime) approach is as close to a "Physics fast forward" as you're going to get with Unity. Is your actual question about that, or about how to gracefully hide the fast forward from users? (Maybe something else?)

Comment: @ChrisMills-Price I understand Unity is very limited when it comes to handling things outside of the sandbox provided by the scripting engine. So I'm just looking for a way to hide the physics fast forward. Maybe just displaying a loading message while running the scene hidden would do, but if there is a better method I would rather not increase the "loading times" between the scenes.

Comment: I think if you try to pass a lot of time with Time.timeScale, Unity will attempt to process physics before the frame renders. Depending on the complexity of your simulation, it might not be noticeable. (Edit: I base this belief on https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html, which alleges that the physics step can be processed multiple times per frame.)